# How align a popup once its popup? (show a particular part of the popped up page)

Tags: php, javascript, popup

I have a js code to make a simple popup, but i'm trying to align the page once it is popped up. meaning once the user clicks the popup link I only want a participial part of the page to show. I don't need the header and sidebars to show just the content of the page.

Is this possible?

here is my current code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Popup window code
    function newPopup(url) {
            popupWindow = window.open(url,'popUpWindow','height=700,width=700,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
    }
</script>

<a href="javascript:newPopup('<?php the_permalink() ?>');">Click here to Player</a>
```

Comment: Do you control the page in the pop up? Is it in the same domain?

Comment: I'm wondering whether what you really want is not a full window, but rather a modal popup with just content.

Comment: Yes it's a Wordpress site basically I'm building a store for someone to sell music and on the front page I am trying to put "click here to play" the player is already inside the post but just so customer can preview the song I want the post to pop up but be already aligned and centered on the player when it's popped up

Answer (score 0):

Use an anchor, e.g.

```
http://example.com/somepage.html#jump_to_here
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and inside the page:

```
<a name="jump_to_here">Yoohoo, here I am!</a>
```